# How to use two external OAuth 2 OWIN providers (for separate login and fetching of LinkedIn profile data)

Tags: c#, razor, oauth, linkedin-api, owin

We wish to allow login to an MVC Razor website, with the usual assortment of OAuth providers:

e.g.

- Google/Google+
- Microsoft Account
- Facebook
- LinkedIn

These all work perfectly fine by themselves, but we need to have the additional option to **import the user's profile data, specifically from LinkedIn** regardless of how they login.

As a test of fetching a LinkedIn profile, we successfully stored the access token from `LinkedIn` in the `ApplicationUser` object like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            //check claims here
            if (info.Login.LoginProvider.ToLower()=="linkedin")
            {
                var claim = info.ExternalIdentity.Claims.First(p => p.Type == "urn:linkedin:accesstoken");
                if (claim != null)
                {
                    user.OAuthAccessToken = claim.Value;
                }
            }

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

And fetch that token back later with:

```
 var usertoken = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).OAuthAccessToken;
```

But of course this only works if they signed in with LinkedIn.

What we really want is to login via OAuth, with say Google, and then optionally have the user login to their the LinkedIn account to get the access token and fetch the profile data.

Does OWIN support making an additional OAuth login *that does not change the current login*? There is so much framework code provided by the latest Razor templates, I am not sure of the best way to do this.

Comment: Can you please share the solution for this problem. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Illep: Does it look like we ever received a solution for this? We parked that feature for future investigation. Sorry:(

Comment: Since this question was posted in 2014, I was under the impression that you might have found an answer by now.

Comment: @Illep: Nah... Very long project. Just releasing first version to test this week.